# Remover itens de um array de objetos

Tags: javascript, dom

Estou tentando remover alguns itens de um array de objetos, sao eles: categoria, descricao e add

```
function addCarrinho(event) {
console.log(addCarrinho)
const aComprar = event.target
if (aComprar.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
    const cardProduto = aComprar.closest('li')
    const cardProdutoClone = cardProduto.cloneNode(true)
    delete cardProdutoClone.categoria
    delete cardProdutoClone.descricao
    delete cardProdutoClone.add

    orgarnizarCar.appendChild(cardProdutoClone)

}
```

}

tentei dessa forma e de algumas outras e nao obtive sucesso. gostaria de uma pequena ajuda aqui, sou iniciante. obrigado!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

opa cara, aparentemente basta definir `cardProdutoClone` como variável(var) ao invés de definir como constante(const).
constantes não podem ser alteradas, por isso voce não consegue deletar as propriedades